# Bash - Error parsing ~ in environment variable

Tags: bash, double-quotes, tilde-expansion

I have environment variable `export MY_WORK_DIR="~/project"`.
While I'm using below command, it give me an error:

```sh
realpath $MY_WORK_DIR

realpath: '~/project': No such file or directory
```

In my guess, the `~` is not processed while using this env variable.

BTW, `export MY_WORK_DIR=~/project` is not an option for me. `~` should be in the string.

Could you please guide me how to get real path from envrionment variable `~/project` ?

#### EDIT

Sorry. The variable is from other app so I cannot modify the environment variable which contains tilde. (Storing variable with tilde expanded form is not an option).

#### EDIT2

Is it safe to use `eval` command like this? `eval "echo ${MY_WORK_DIR}"`. It works for my use.

Comment: Sorry. The variable is from other app so I cannot modify the environment variable which contains tilde. (Storing variable with tilde expanded form is not an option). I just want to know how can I properly get the real path from tilde included variable.

Comment: Okay, I have reopened the question.

Comment: Oh. I tried eval command. It works as expected. Is it safe to use eval command?
eval "echo ${MY_WORK_DIR}"

Comment: If you cannot modify the env variable then your option is only `eval`, I'm afraid. `eval realpath "$MY_WORK_DIR"`, eval is not safe since it can expand/execute arbitrary commands in a variable (shell injection 101) so use it at your own risks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use `eval` if I can avoid it. Especially in the way you are doing it, this is an invitation to do havoc by embedding dangerous code into `MY_WORK_DIR`.

A cheap solution for your concrete example would be to do a

```
if [[ ${MY_WORK_DIR:0:1} == '~' ]]
then 
  MY_WORK_DIR="$HOME/${MY_WORK_DIR:1}"
fi
```

which chops off the annoying `~` and prepends your home directory. But this would fail if `MY_WORK_DIR` is set to, say, `~einstein/project`.

In this case, you would have to extract the user name (`einstein`) and search the home directory for this user.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps can provide a resolution:

1. You need to replace "~" with the full path of the project directory.
2. Use `pwd` command to identify the full path of the project directory; e.g. `/root/Documents/project` is the full path you get.
3. Execute this command `export MY_WORK_PROJECT=/root/Documents/project`
4. Execute this command `echo $MY_WORK_PROJECT` so you should get this result
   `/root/Documents/project`

Comment: For step 2: Why not use `$PWD` instead?

Comment: The output path resulting from executing `PWD` or `$PWD` is same which is in this case `/root/Documents/project`

Comment: The effect is the same, but you create a child process unnecessarily. This may matter, if the code in question is executed repeatedly in a loop and is the reason why I would go for ``$PWD. OTOH, `$(pwd)` is **always correct**, while `$PWD` may "lie" in the pathological case that someone had assigned explicitly `PWD=....` before. At least it might make sense presenting both alternatives and explaining the pros and cons, so the OP can understand the difference and choose as he likes.